include in template doesn't accept filter richtext
Two Page-classes have nearly the same structure, so the templates for these classes are also nearly the same. So I put template code into a component and include this code into the templates.
The template code which is included contains "    {{ notiert.kurzfassung|richtext }}
". This produces an error:

raise TemplateSyntaxError("Invalid filter: '%s'" % filter_name)
django.template.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: Invalid filter: 'richtext'

Why?

You need to load the richtext filter by putting the tag {% load wagtailcore_tags %} at the top of the template. This needs to be done on every template file that uses the filter (it won't be carried across on includes).
